# Wordpress too many redirect error when removing the port from site url

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I am running wordpress site on apache server on 8080 which is behind nginx reverse proxy server running on 80.

So if I set my site url as mydomain.com:8080 in wordpress admin settings, all is working fine. But if I remove the port, I get too many redirect error in browser when accessing website.

What I am trying to do is trying to have my site url without port 8080. Right now public can access my site without port 8080 (by hitting my site on nginx port 80). But the issue is when wordpress loads the page in browser, all urls on the page have 8080 in them which I do not want as web crawlers will include this port number when crawling my site.

Any help would be highly appreciated. So in short, I want wordpress to render all urls without port 8080. Can we do this using .htaccess file or is there any better way to do it. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: Yes I did clear the cache

Comment: What is your nginx configuration?